# GroupBy issue how to get last id?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have four related tables and, using the following query, combine them with 4 `LEFT JOIN` and 2 `MAX()` aggregate functions:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
         id,
         cognome,
         nome,
         sesso,
         pr_sedute_complessive,
         presa_in_carico_data,
         cf,
         cnome,
         tdr_cognome,
         tdr_nome,
         COUNT(tbl_trattamenti.trt_id),
         MAX(tbl_trattamenti.data),
         pr_id
FROM     tbl_aziente p1
  LEFT JOIN comuni
         ON comuni.cid = p1.nascita_luogo 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_cartellaclinica
         ON tbl_cartellaclinica.pz_fk_id = p1.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_progetto
         ON tbl_progetto.cc_id_fk = tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_fisioterapista
         ON tbl_fisioterapista.tdr_id = tbl_progetto.pr_fisioterapista_fk 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_trattamenti
         ON tbl_progetto.pr_id = tbl_trattamenti.pr_fk_id 
WHERE    idoneo = 'y'
     AND p1.tipo_assistenza = 4
GROUP BY p1.id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This is all okay, except for one thing: I want the record from `tbl_progetto` which has the highest `id` rather than the first.  I've tried to use `MAX(primaryKey)`, but I then get only the key - not the record having that pKey.

Comment: What do you mean by "last inserted id"?  MySQL doesn't keep track of the order in which records are inserted into a table.

Comment: query get a list of users and related projects (tbl_progetto) how can retrieve projects with high ID (primary key) in same query ?

Comment: @Double  I tried to use a subquery (ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) but return me only one row...

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  "last inserted id" and "high ID" are not the same thing.

Comment: sorry my mistake, high ID is my goal ! Not last inserted

Comment: from tbl_progetto: **pr_sedute_complessive, presa_in_carico_data, pr_id**

Comment: it get me **pr_sedute_complessive** with the first (pKey) of three row actual exist in db. I wish the high (the third)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic principle is that you need to reference `tbl_progetto` *twice* - once in a subquery that identifies the `id` of the records of interest, and a second time to fetch the rest of that record.

Assuming that there is a many-to-one relationship between `tbl_cartellaclinica` and `tbl_progetto`, the subquery would be:

```
SELECT   tbl_cartellaclinica.pz_fk_id, MAX(tbl_progetto.pr_id) AS pr_id
FROM     tbl_cartellaclinica
    JOIN tbl_progetto
      ON tbl_progetto.cc_id_fk = tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id
GROUP BY tbl_cartellaclinica.pz_fk_id
```

And therefore your modified query would be:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
         id,
         cognome,
         nome,
         sesso,
         pr_sedute_complessive,
         presa_in_carico_data,
         cf,
         cnome,
         tdr_cognome,
         tdr_nome,
         COUNT(tbl_trattamenti.trt_id),
         MAX(tbl_trattamenti.data),
         t.pr_id
FROM     tbl_aziente p1
  LEFT JOIN comuni
         ON comuni.cid = p1.nascita_luogo 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_cartellaclinica
         ON tbl_cartellaclinica.pz_fk_id = p1.id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT   tbl_cartellaclinica.pz_fk_id, MAX(tbl_progetto.pr_id) AS pr_id
    FROM     tbl_cartellaclinica
        JOIN tbl_progetto
          ON tbl_progetto.cc_id_fk = tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id
    GROUP BY tbl_cartellaclinica.pz_fk_id
  ) AS t ON t.pz_fk_id = tbl_cartellaclinica.pz_fk_id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_progetto
         ON tbl_progetto.cc_id_fk = tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id
        AND tbl_progetto.pr_id = t.pr_id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_fisioterapista
         ON tbl_fisioterapista.tdr_id = tbl_progetto.pr_fisioterapista_fk 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_trattamenti
         ON tbl_progetto.pr_id = tbl_trattamenti.pr_fk_id 
WHERE    idoneo = 'y'
     AND p1.tipo_assistenza = 4
GROUP BY p1.id
LIMIT    0, 10
```

Comment: thanks eggyval but return me **#1052 - Column 'pr_id' in field list is ambiguous**

Comment: ok I removed it from the SELECT. I am indebted to you, I do not know how to thank you. They were two days I tried to get out! thank you very much

Comment: @paskuale: You could thank me by [accepting my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it solved your problem and [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it if you found it useful or helpful!  :)

Comment: This is a query managed from php for datatable jQuery object :( seem don't like table names with dots.

Comment: eggyval one quest ... why COUNT(tbl_trattamenti.trt_id) return me 0 ? Was 2 on old query ...

Comment: @paskuale: There are fewer rows within each group now that you're only joining with `tbl_progetto` on one of its matches rather than all of them; `COUNT(tbl_trattamenti.trt_id)` was previously giving you that count across *all* `tbl_progetto`.

Comment: @eggyval: hi with same tables, different query, I want a list of 'tbl_cartellaclinica' and it's last 'tbl_progetto.id' data ? Where are difference ? tnx

Comment: <blockquote>SELECT * FROM tbl_cartellaclinica LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT   tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id, MAX(tbl_progetto.pr_id) AS pr_id
    FROM     tbl_cartellaclinica
        JOIN tbl_progetto
          ON tbl_progetto.cc_id_fk = tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id
    GROUP BY tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id) as t
ON
t.cc_id = tbl_cartellaclinica.cc_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_progetto ON
tbl_progetto.pr_id = t.pr_id</blockquote>